# How to read file name input by user by function

Tags: c++

I try to input a filename to a string, then use `ifstream` to load the file in the `void` function. But I call it in another function, it do not load the content of the file. How can I solve this problem?

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void inputfilename()
{ 
    ifstream file;
    string name;
    getline(cin, name);
    name.append(".txt");
    file.open(name);    
    if ( !file )
    cout << "Error File" << endl;
}

void getColRow(int &row, int &col)
{
    ifstream file;
    inputfilename();
    file >> col;
    file >> row;
    file.close();
}

int main()
{    
    int col, row;
    getColRow(row, col);
    cout << col << ":" << row << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The two `ifstream`s are totally unrelated. You have one called `file` in `inputfilename` and another one called `file` in `getColRow`.

You can return the stream from the function to use it:

```
ifstream inputfilename()
{ 
    ifstream file;
    string name;
    getline(cin, name);
    name.append(".txt");
    file.open(name);    
    if ( !file )
    cout << "Error File" << endl;
    return file;
}

void getColRow(int &row, int &col)
{
    ifstream file = inputfilename();
    file >> col;
    file >> row;
    file.close();
}
```

Comment: Note, `ifsteam` does not support copying, so this approach will only work in C++11 and later if the `ifstream` is moved instead of copied.

Answer (score 2):

The `ifstream` in `inputfilename()` has nothing to do with the `ifstream` in `getColRow()`.  The `ifstream` in `getColRow()` has no filename assigned to it, so it is not opening the file, and thus has no data to read from.

I would suggest simply having `inputfilename()` return the filename it read, and let the caller decide what to do with that filename, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string inputfilename()
{ 
    string name;
    if ( getline(cin, name) )
        name.append(".txt");
    return name;
}

void getColRow(int &row, int &col)
{
    ifstream file(inputfilename());
    if ( !file.is_open() ) {
        cout << "Error Opening File" << endl;
        col = row = -1;
    }
    else if ( !(file >> col >> row) ) {
        cout << "Error Reading File" << endl;
        col = row = -1;
    }
}

int main()
{    
    int col, row;
    getColRow(row, col);
    cout << col << ":" << row << endl;

    return 0;
}
```